# Update Database table from a dataframe in R

Tags: sql, r, rodbc

I have a tabe -`table1` in DB as below:

```
FN  FD  IND
123 Tx1 Q
124 Tx2 Q
125 Tx3 Q
126 Tx4 Q
127 Tx5 Q
128 Tx6 Q
129 Tx7 Q1
130 Tx8 Q1
131 Tx9 Q1
132 T10 Q1
```

I run the following code - to fetch records

```
library(RODBC)
channel <- odbcConnect("R",uid="root",pwd="password@123")
mytable <- sqlQuery(channel, paste(" SELECT * 
                                     from schema.table1 
                                     where Ind="Q1"", sep="" ))
```

Now `mytable` has 4 records.
My question is - I need to update the column `IND` as Q2 for these 4 records (Which means i read those records into R)

The Table `mytable` can have More records (500 records) in future extraction.
How can i update the column `IND` as Q2 for those records that i fetch from DB(ie. `mytable` in R). I am using `SQL Developer` as DB.

I tried - below code - but i can do it for 1 record.

```
update.query <- paste("UPDATE schema.table1 ", 
                       "SET IND='Q2'",
                       "WHERE FN ='129'", sep="")
dummy <- sqlQuery(channel, update.query)
```

`mytable` is a dataframe in R. And `table1` is a table in a DB.I am not allowed to create a temporary table in DB.

Comment: It seems to me just a `SQL` syntax question which has nothing to do with R really. Maybe add a `SQL` tag and rephrase this question as it was a `SQL` only. When you will get your query from `SQL` users, just parse it into `sqlQuery`

Comment: `Mytable` is a dataframe in R. And `table1` is a table in a DB.I am not allowed to create a temproray table in DB.If i can do so i can modify my `where` clause and update - with both the tables lying in the DB.

Comment: It doesn't seem that `table1` depends on what you do with `mytable` in R. As I understand your question, all you want to do is to update the `table1` after you pull some data from it to R. So you can do it all in `SQL`, as `SQL` doesn't need any information back from R. All you basically need to do is to find out how to update a `SQL` table after you pulled some data from it that's all

Comment: Exactly !. Thanks i have added SQL Tag.